# Python: Multiprocessing Hive queries

Tags: python, sql, hive, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to execute multiple Hive queries by passing the table names from map i.e.

```
from pyhive import hive
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

conn = hive.connect('hive_connection',99999,
                          username='user',
                          password='password',
                          auth='LDAP')

query = 'select * from hive_db.{hive_table_name} limit 500'.format(hive_table_name=hive_table_name)

def hivetable(hive_table_name):
    query = 'select * from hive_db.{hive_table_name} limit 10'.format(table_name=hive_table_name)
    result = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    p = Pool(5)
    print p.map(((hivetable, ['hive_table1','hive_table2','hive_table3'])))
```

but getting:

```
TypeError: map() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

How can I achieve multiprocessing here and resolve the ongoing issue?
Tried other references but couldn't find any about the SQL one.

Any help/ suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you have so many extra parenthesis, when you are calling a `map` function.

Try this and it should work without any issue.

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    p = Pool(5)
    print p.map(hivetable, ['hive_table1','hive_table2','hive_table3'])
```

I am considering that actual table you want to process is higher than 3, otherwise it doesn't make sense to create 5 threads on 3 tables.